# NodeJS sometimes gets killed because out of memory while streaming/piping files

Tags: node.js, memory, streaming, node-request

### Problem

I have a NodeJS Server with the [request module](https://github.com/request/request).
I use [requests](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) `pipe()` for serving files.

Sometimes, the app throws an exception, all downloads cancel and I have to restart the app:

> Out of memory: Kill process 9342 (nodejs) score 793 or sacrifice child
>   Killed process 9342 (nodejs) total-vm:1333552kB, anon-rss:410648kB, file-rss:0kB

I wrote another script which restarts the server automatically (with childprocess & fork) when it ends unexpectedly, which sometimes throws this error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory

Server data
RAM: 500MB (I know that this is not much, but it's cheap)
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
NodeJS version: v0.10.36

### Assumptions

1. Too much downloads in parallel
2. Something wrong with pipe related to the RAM

Regarding 1:
When somebody downloads a big file a bit of it is loaded in the RAM (I know nothing about this, say 20MB at once, please correct me if I'm too wrong). When 400MB is available and 20 current downloads with the same download speed, the server crashes because he can't load more than 400MB at once in the RAM.

Regarding 2:
In addition to `pipe()` I use the following code to track current & canceled downloads:

```
req.on("close", function() { 
    currentDownloads--;
});
```

The `pipe()` doesn't close properly and the RAM it used doesn't get cleared.

### Questions

If any of my assumptions should be right, how could I fix it? 
If not, what could it be or rather where could be the cause (is it NodeJS/request module/is my code wrong or bad, are there better methods)?

### Full Code

```
var currentDownloads = 0;
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    var open = false;

    req.on("close", function () {
        if (open) {
            currentDownloads--;
            open = false;
        }
    });

    request.get(url)
    .on("error", function (err) {
        log("err " + err);
        if (open) {
            currentDownloads--;
            open = false;
        }
    })
    .on("response", function () {
        open = true;
        currentDownloads++;
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Please show the actual node.js code you're using that is causing the problem.  Large downloads are certainly possible so whatever the issue is is probably related to your specific code.

Comment: Added my code, but it's not special..